# CSS - Плавное изменение высоты в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: css, вёрстка, angular

У меня есть `div`, внутри которого изменяются разделы. Разделы имеют разную высоту.

При переходе от одного к другому высота `div` должна изменяться плавно. Пробовал ставить `transition` на `div`.

Дополнение:
Я делаю на Angular. Внутри `div` стоит `router-outlet`. При переходе с одной страницы на другую его содержимое меняется. Изменяется и высота. Как сделать изменение высоты плавным, как если бы оно было со свойством `transition`?

Comment: Нет, я делаю на Angular. Внутри `div` стоит `<router-outlet>`. Это тэг, содержимое которого меняется в зависимости от пути (url).

Comment: Ок, не подумал, что это может иметь отношение к делу. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал.

Comment: я не  докапался а  просто изначально вопрос кажется из рубрики css а на самом деле это касается angular

Comment: Нужно ли приводить код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам придется находить скриптом исходное и конечное значение высоты `div` или `router-outlet` и проставлять их соответствующему элементу на лету - только тогда transition отработает. Браузер вычисляет все промежуточные значения свойств, на которые действует transition, ориентируясь на их начальное и конечное значения. А оных значений у элементов с неизвестными заранее свойствами (в вашем случае - чему равна `height`, если она `auto`?), разумеется, нет.

Comment: Спасибо за качественный ответ. Нельзя ли то же самое реализовать другим способом?

Comment: другим способом - это с JS. имхо, самый оптимальный вариант - как я уже написал, скриптом проставлять высоту, а уж плавный переход предоставить браузеру с работающим `transition`. Минус тут только один: рассчитать высоту блока с заранее неизвестным количеством контента, да еще и в зависимости от размеров окна браузера - та еще задача...

Comment: А что, если на блок, который должен меняться по высоте, повесить `сабтри мутэйшен обсервер`. Ему самому задать фиксированную высоту и `оверфлоу хиден`, а при изменении контента, задавать высоту равную высоте контента дочернего элемента?

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели что-то типа такого?

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  content.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

#btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content.active::before {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, sunt incidunt quos eligendi in esse iure eum quam aperiam nulla vero delectus sequi ipsam aut sit modi distinctio corrupti dolor?
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, sunt incidunt quos eligendi in esse iure eum quam aperiam nulla vero delectus sequi ipsam aut sit modi distinctio corrupti dolor?
</div>
<div id="btn">Клик</div>
```

Можно, конечно, менять высоту, но это плохо анимировать `height`, `width`, `margin`, `padding`: браузер перерисовывает страницу, когда мы анимируем эти свойства, это затратно по производительности

```js
content.style.height = content.scrollHeight + 'px';

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const height = content.scrollHeight;
  content.classList.toggle('active');
  if (content.classList.contains('active')) {
    content.style.height = '0px';
  } else {
    content.style.height = height + 'px';
  }
});

const ipsum = ' Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.';

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (value > 9) return false; // чтобы нельзя было большие куски просто вводить в блок
  for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    content.innerHTML += ipsum;
  }
  content.style.height = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

#btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, sunt incidunt quos eligendi in esse iure eum quam aperiam nulla vero delectus sequi ipsam aut sit modi distinctio corrupti dolor? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Exercitationem, sunt incidunt quos eligendi in esse iure eum quam aperiam nulla vero delectus sequi ipsam aut sit modi distinctio corrupti dolor?
</div>
<div id="btn">Клик</div>
<input id="input" type="number" placeholder="Вводи 1-9 цифры">
```

Comment: Не совсем, я не знаю точно высоту разделов. Высота `div` - `height: auto`. Спасибо за старания.

Comment: @FeironoX5 во 2 примере я меняю `height`, я опираюсь на scrollHeight - максимальную высоту блока и всё

Comment: @FeironoX5 играйся, изменил 2 вариант